# How can I return user logged in data using Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an iOS application that has a login system. When a user signs up, this populates the backend database in the "Authentication" and "Firestore Database" modules, however when the user navigates to the below page, it should display their "firstname", which is stored in the database as a string. It returns their UID fine, but it just returns the following in the console:

> UserID:  Snapshot Value: Optional() No userData found

Here is my data structure, for reference. [Database Outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIQFG.png)

Here is my code, how can I get this working?

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore


class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var welcomeLabel: UILabel!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        fetchUserData()
        
    }
        
        func fetchUserData() {
            
            if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
                let userId = currentUser.uid
                print("UserID:", userId)  // Debugging
                
                let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userId)
                
                userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
                    print("Snapshot Value:", snapshot.value)  // Debugging
                    
                    if let userData = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                        if let firstName = userData["firstname"] as? String {
                            print("FirstName:", firstName)  // Debugging
                            // Update the welcomeLabel with the user's first name
                            self.welcomeLabel.text = "Hello, \(firstName)"
                        } else {
                            print("Firstname not found in userData")
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("No userData found")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Here are my database rules, which seem to allow for read/write.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are your database rules really all on one line like you show here?

Comment: No, these are on separate lines. I have updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like uou're using the wrong database reference.

`let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userId)`

`Database.database()` is for Realtime database not Firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database

You said you are storing data in Firestore, so you should be using `Firestore.firestore()`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data